# Proving $(\lambda^{-1}-A^{-1})^{-1}=\lambda-\lambda^2(\lambda-A)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, let $A\subset X\oplus X$ be a linear relation and let $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\}$

I want to prove that $(\lambda^{-1}-A^{-1})^{-1}=\lambda-\lambda^2(\lambda-A)^{-1}$.

Note that $A=\lambda-R(\lambda,A)^{-1}=\lambda-(\lambda -A)$; hence

$\lambda-\lambda^2(\lambda-A)^{-1}=\lambda-\lambda^2(\lambda-\lambda+(\lambda-A))=\lambda-\lambda^2(\lambda-A)$

which would imply that $(\lambda-A)^{-1}=(\lambda -A)$, but that can't be correct. I would appreciate some hints on solving this problem

Comment: In the middle in the line after hence you lost an exponent $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor out $\lambda^{-1}A^{-1}$ and follow your nose:
\begin{align}
   (\lambda^{-1}-A^{-1})^{-1} &= \{ \lambda^{-1}A^{-1}(A-\lambda))^{-1} \\
    &= (A-\lambda)^{-1}\lambda A \\
    &= (A-\lambda)^{-1}(\lambda (A-\lambda)+\lambda) \\
    &= \lambda-\lambda^2(A-\lambda)^{-1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

It works in the reals without commuting multiplication, so it should work here.
$$\begin {align}\lambda-\lambda^2(\lambda-A)^{-1} &=[(\lambda^2-\lambda A)-\lambda)^2](\lambda-A)^{-1}\\
&=-\lambda A(\lambda - A)^{-1}\\
&=-(A^{-1}-\lambda^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=(\lambda^{-1}-A^{-1})^{-1}\end {align}$$